# How can I add a pragma to C# code generated by a pre-processed T4 template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

I have some pre-processed T4 templates generating C# code - but the generated code causes compiler warnings like "Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member ...".

To prevent the warnings, I would like to embed '#pragma warning disable 1591' into the code generated by the T4 processor.

Is there some way that I can embed the pragma into my template so that it appears in the generated code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set it at a project level in the project settings I'm afraid.
We've fixed that specific issue in Visual Studio 2012, so they should build warning clean.

Comment: Thanks.  At least I know not to waste time looking for a solution.